# Puzzle - Gears of War

Tags: gears-of-war

I'm trying to solve a puzzle from gears of war but I'm not getting the correct answer.

This is a bunch of keys from StarCraft II and the icons need to be translated into the words they mean I suppose.

[image]

This picture basically says: "Painkillers are to Max Payne as ? is to Gears of War".

Answers that I've tried:

Gears of War: Crimson Omen, Cover, Roadie Run, Dom, Chainsaw

Need help with this. Thank you.

Comment: Consider splitting these 2 questions up in different ones, have you tried searching on the internet or game forums too?

Comment: I got the answer for StarCraft 2. Its move stop hold patrol attack. But for Gears of War, I've spent more than 2 hours looking for that but couldn't find anything that relates to the effect of Painkillers in Max Payne.

Comment: What's the source for this question?  It doesn't seem to be coming from a game.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for help with a puzzle, not a question related to gaming.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Can you please put your comments on this meta https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12684? I'd like to have something to point to in the future when this issue arises again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Max Payne Wiki on [Painkillers](http://maxpayne.wikia.com/wiki/Painkillers)

> **Effects**
>   Heals 20% of health (Max Payne 1&2)

So we know we're looking for something that heals.

From the Gears of War Wiki on [Health and Damage](http://gearsofwar.wikia.com/wiki/Health_and_damage)

> Gears of War doesn't have a traditional health bar, nor does it have health packs or first aid kits that you must find in order to heal your player
>   ...
>   Once the character stops taking damage, the red omen fades just as gradually as it appears, and the character eventually returns to full health.

So you would be looking for either 'wait' or 'time'.

Comment: Bonus source since Wikis can be hit or miss: I spent hundreds of hours playing Gears of War 1-3.

Answer (score 2):

In Max Payne you use pain killers to restore health.
In gears of war you just have to wait.

"Time" is the answer

Comment: Do you have any sources for this?

Comment: just converted the coments in the question into a proper answer